# Mule - Get the exceptions

Tags: mule

I've implemented a flow performing these steps:

```
<read new rows from db />

<for each row>
    <update row to "processing" />
</for each row>

<for each row>
    <call external web service />
    <update row with ws response  />
</for each row>
```

Now, I have to write the last piece of code: the exceptions management.
But how can I discover which exceptions can be raised by my flow?
For example referring to Java language, if I create an instance of "java.io.File" class I know that a "FileNotFoundException" can be raised if the file doesn't exist ...

How can I do the same with the mule?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

All exceptions raised in a flow are wrapped as an [`org.mule.api.MuleException`](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.6.1/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/MuleException.html)

Look at the exception hierarchy under `org.mule.api.MuleException` to see the main types of exceptions you will receive from Mule (for example you'll get a [`DispatchException`](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.6.1/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html) "*when an endpoint dispatcher fails to send, dispatch or receive a message*".

Mule provides [`org.mule.util.ExceptionUtils`](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.6.1/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/util/ExceptionUtils.html) to help digging in the exception and finding the actual root cause.

Comment: Hi David, I would like to know which exceptions can be raised by my flow and write the code in order to manage them before, not after the exception occurs. For example if I have an exception because the db is unreachable, I want my flow send an email to the dba. Or if the web service is unavailable my flow must alert the system administrator. With your approach I have to wait the exception occurs (probably in a production environment), then investigate it in order to understand what's happened, and finally update my flow for managing it.

Comment: You should then receive a http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.6.1/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html I've extended my answer to say that. Also, don't wait for production to test your flows for failure modes. Your flow should be fully tested for all the failure cases you can think of.

Comment: Thanks David (also for your patience with me, as you can imagine I'm a mule-newbie! :-)). I'm sure the class hierarchy will be very useful to me! But I want to know which exception can be raised by my flow. I don't want to study all the mule exception and then trying to figure out which can be applied to my flow! For example with Java language if I call the "public File[] listFiles()" method of java.io.File, according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html I have to manage a SecurityException. What's the same if I use <db:select> or <http:inbound-endpoint> or ...?

Comment: Not sure what I can say that I haven't said before. All the underlying exceptions (and there are many since Mule is built on so many libraries) are wrapped with Mule exceptions that represent general categories of failures. That's all you need to deal with. If you want to know what are all the possible underlying exceptions, you'll have to read the JavaDoc of the libraries used behind each transport/module that you use.